# JWT token & Refresh token updating from client side

Tags: security, jwt, refresh-token

I have a React Native application with JWT authentication access to my backend.

When the user authenticates the backend returns an `accessToken` and a `refreshToken` the idea is, that both tokens are stored in `AsyncStorage` along with the `expirationTime` stored for both tokens.

Right now the implementation is so there is a `setTimeout` function that checks if the token is about to expire and uses the refreshToken to update the accessToken.

This made me wonder how much of a security upgrade it is using refreshTokens.

If both are stored in `AsyncStorage` (on the client), both could be accessed, what is the point of having the refresh token?

If an attacker got access to the client storage, they could simply update the access token with the refresh token?